# error when trying to add a table cell from a form

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

so I am trying to add a table cell after I have filled up a form but I have a signal SIGABRT error when I try to press the add button in my table view controller

here is my code to try and link to the form

```
if(segue.identifier == "AddShift")
        {
        let ARTnegativeViewController = segue.destination as!
            ARTnegativeViewController
        let shift = Shift(id: "", day: "", slot: "", image:
        "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/4c/14/e14c1452e89b760916a2967a75ad8bfa.jpg")
        ARTnegativeViewController.shift = shift
        }
```

I have 2 view controllers for the form as users can only book a slot once they have picked negative in a picker view. I think this is the part that made me have errors.
The values of id, day and slot are all in the 2nd view controller/ part of the form

This error appeared when I added another segue to the 2nd view controller but before adding the app crashed when I pressed the add button in my table view controller.

Comment: Likely unrelated but a variable with the same name as the type is confusing. Name the variable with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: Which line is causing the error exactly? Do you have an error message in console? Which one? Could it be `segue.destination as! ARTnegativeViewController`? Is there a UINavigationController in between?

Comment: @Larme yep the error occured on that line, and as for a navigation controller I added it at the front of the form after my tab bar controller so it is in this order, 1. tab bar 2. nav controller 3. 1st view controller 2. 2nd vc

Comment: @Larme and as for the table view there is a nav controller 1. tab bar 2. nav controller 3. tablet view w table cell 4. details of the table cell , the segue I added for the add button is from 3 to number 3 and 4 of the comment above

Comment: @vadian I have tried that but it gave the same error :/

Comment: @Larme here is how it looks like https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FLvWbmSNYx7nRexwrVigl5pWSUYKvX7W4Yp0b1Vr5_8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If it's `as!`  that causes the crash, there you should have an error message in console. Read it, share it...

Comment: This line `let ARTnegativeViewController = segue.destination as! ARTnegativeViewController` doesn't make any sense. `ARTnegativeViewController` is a class and you can't make a class a var. Something like `let mycontroller = segue.destination as! ARTnegativeViewController` would make more sense. Also remember that in coding, var's start with lowercased letter and Class, Struct and Enum's start with Uppercase

Comment: @Larme Could not cast value of type 'DIF.BookingViewController' (0x107107b10) to 'DIF.ARTnegativeViewController' this is the error msg

Comment: `segue.destination` is a `BookingViewController` not a `ARTnegativeViewController`, that's the crash reason. Could you check that at the end of the segue with `AddShift` it's the correct ViewController? Or the correct segue identifier ?